# Node.Js MongoDB format date while getting List

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm New to Node.Js and MongoDB . Am getting Date as CreatedDate : 2018-09-06T06:14:53.111Z . In output am trying to display as "MM/DD/YYYY" .

Here is my code am getting last 60 days data form Collection.

```
 var today = new Date();

    today.setDate(today.getDate() - 60);

    ODSCase.find({ UserGUID: req.UserGUID ,CreatedDate:{"$gte":new Date(today)} }).sort({ModifiedDate: -1})
   .exec()
   .then(doc => {
       res.status(200).json(doc);
   })
   .catch(err =>{ err500.err500(err,req,res,next);});
```

Output:

```
 {

    "_id": "5b9242aed7ae250c74325362",
    "CustomerGUID": "ee1ac5c7-c0f9-466c-8859-95dc1fcd0334",
    "InstanceGUID": "878aee54-1b95-46d1-9e26-b9eaea9f9cd4",
    "UserGUID": "f0272467-3ec5-48f7-5553-987900b57a11",
    "CaseNumber": 1536311981016,
    "CaseStatus": "New",
    "CampaignID": "66336533-3765-3266-4d43-382f392f3230",
    "CreatedDate": "2018-09-07T09:19:42.586Z",
    "CreatedBy": "f0272467-3ec5-48f7-5553-987900b57a11",
    "ModifiedDate": "2018-09-07T09:19:42.586Z",
    "ModifiedBy": "f0272467-3ec5-48f7-5553-987900b57a11",
    "IsDeleted": false,
    "Source": "Dev",
    "__v": 0
},
```

Comment: With a ODM as mongoose you can override the method toObject to give format to some attributes. Another option is before then use map and give format with some module as https://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider running an aggregate pipeline instead which allows you to use operators such as **[`$dateToString`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/)** that can transform the date to the desired format.

For example, the same query above can be run using the aggregation framework as:

```
let today = new Date();
today.setDate(today.getDate() - 60);

const date = new Date(today);

ODSCase.aggregate([
    { '$match': { 
        'UserGUID': req.UserGUID,
        'CreatedDate': { '$gte': date } 
    } },
    { '$sort': { 'ModifiedDate': -1 } },
    { '$addFields': {
        'CreatedDate': { 
            '$dateToString': { 
                'format': '%m/%d/%Y', 
                'date': '$CreatedDate' 
            }
        }
    } } 
])
.exec()
.then(doc => {
    res.status(200).json(doc);
})
.catch(err => err500.err500(err, req, res, next) );
```

You can also use the excellent [Moment.js JavaScript date library](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/subtract/) to create the date object used in the query:

```
const moment = require('moment');
const date = moment().subtract(60, 'days').toDate(); // or...
const date = moment().add(-60, 'days').toDate();
```

Comment: Hi chridam , Am getting  "Error": "The aggregation pipeline is not enabled for this account. Please see https://aka.ms/mongodb-aggregation for details." . Am trying to set aggregate enable in Azure Portal .. I will try this and Let you Know . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to deal only with the date format in output which is currently in ISO string to make it in the form of mm/dd/yyyy, you can try this:

```
var today = new Date();

    today.setDate(today.getDate() - 60);

    ODSCase.find({ UserGUID: req.UserGUID ,CreatedDate:{"$gte":new Date(today)} }).sort({ModifiedDate: -1})
   .exec()
   .then(doc => {
       doc.CreatedDate = new Date(doc.CreatedDate).toLocaleDateString('en-US');
       res.status(200).json(doc);
   })
   .catch(err =>{ err500.err500(err,req,res,next);});
```

Comment: Hi Ashish , No change in Output :   "CreatedDate": "2018-09-07T09:19:42.586Z", with your answer

Comment: Edited. There was a typo, apologies.